# Build Cordova Apps using Windows 10 SDK - No Valid MSBuilD

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, uwp

I have installed the Windows 10 SDK on my Windows 10 PC, but unfortunately I'm unable to build the cordova apps. It give error "Error: No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target." I have google it but some are saying need to install MS Visual Studio, it really frustrating me because this MS Visual Studio is 9GB that so big in size. Is there anything that I can do with Windows 10 SDK or should I download the MS Visual Studio instead?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a number of necessary components required to build and package a UWP app for distribution. You will need to install Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using 'Command Prompt' and not some other terminal like 'Node JS Command Prompt'

Also, there have been changes since this post that may help you.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/27/cordova-windows-6.0.0.html