# VS2015 - No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed Cordova with VS2015. When I build Cordova solution in VS2015 I get below error for windows platform.

```
"No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target"
```

when I run "cordova requirements" I got below information. For me, build successful with android platform.

```
Requirements check results for windows:
Windows OS: installed Windows 10
MSBuild Tools: not installed
MSBuild tools v.14.0 not found. Please install Visual Studio 2015 Community from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
Visual Studio: not installed
Required version of Visual Studio not found. Please install Visual Studio 2015 Community from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
Windows SDK: not installed
Windows SDK not found. Ensure that you have installed Windows 10.0 SDK along with Visual Studio or install Windows 10.0 SDK separately from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads
Windows Phone SDK: not installed
Windows Phone SDK not found. Ensure that you have installed Windows Phone 10.0 SDK along with Visual Studio or install Windows Phone 10.0 SDK separately from https://dev.windows.com/develop/download-phone-sdk
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

I saw the same issue in the below links, but that didn't help to me.

["No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target" when build cordova with Microsoft visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219609/no-valid-msbuild-was-detected-for-the-selected-target-when-build-cordova-with)

[Build Cordova Apps using Windows 10 SDK - No Valid MSBuilD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359688/build-cordova-apps-using-windows-10-sdk-no-valid-msbuild)

Hope someone can help me with these problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Windows SDK and other requirements mentioned in log is not installed , should be installed from VS setup.

Comment: I installed cordova from vs setup only but still Im gettig this issue. Is there any configuration that I have to check for building application?

Comment: Beside cordova you need to install Windows SDk and ..

Comment: Look like "cordova build" access registry. I don't have access to registry. Is there a way to give the location of MSbuild tools manually without access registry.